# Attempt to revert to Postsharp 4.x from 5.x fails

Tags: postsharp

I installed Postsharp 5.0.41, then discovered that my solution (in VS2017) depends on Postsharp 4.x. So, I uninstalled Postsharp 5.x, ran the installer for Postsharp 4.3.41, which tells me "Postsharp Tools for Visual Studio is already installed and up to date."

It won't let me install Postsharp 4.3.41! (it still lets me reinstall 5.x)

I need to get past this stuck point quickly, either with 4.x or 5.x. Upgrading the project to 5.x is an option, but the upgrade path is unclear and seems possibly time consuming. Time I don't have. Preferably, I install 4.x and move on.

How do I clean out the 5.x installation enough to allow 4.x installation to move forward?

Thanks,
wbp

Comment: More info: To uninstall PS 5.x, I performed the actions "Removing Postsharp from Visual Studio" in this post, http://doc.postsharp.net/uninstalling

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that PostSharp has two components:

1. Compiler and libraries that are distributed as NuGet packages.
2. PostSharp Tools - Visual Studio extension that provides UI in Visual Studio.

For optimal experience you would want to install the same version of both components, however this is not strictly necessary. You can have PostSharp Tools 5.0 installed in your VS, and install version 4.3 of NuGet packages in your projects.

To answer your question about uninstalling PostSharp Tools 5.0. Please make sure you went through "Uninstalling the PostSharp Tools for Visual Studio" procedure (http://doc.postsharp.net/uninstalling) for all versions of Visual Studio that are installed on your machine. You can check whether the extension is still installed in the "Extensions and Updates" dialogue in VS.

Comment: Alex, Thanks for the response. Apologies, but the uninstall link you mentioned is the one I ran. (See my "More info" comment above .) So, despite that I ran the whole procedure, which appears to have been successful, it will not allow me to install PS 4.x again. So, the question is, is there a work around (registry edit?) which would allow the install process to go forward? Thanks.

Comment: I've just realized that you're trying to install PostSharp Tools 4.3 into VS 2017. However VS 2017 is only supported in PostSharp 5.0+. As I've mentioned in the answer, you can still install PostSharp 4.3 NuGet packages into your project if you're not ready to upgrade to 5.0. You don't need to install VS extension to use PostSharp, or you can install version 5.0 without upgrading your project to 5.0.